# Complex Select Query in 5 table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 5 table:

1. mp3s
2. albums
3. remixes
4. users
5. likes

likes table:

```
╔════════╦══════════╦═════════╦═════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ id     ║ user_id  ║ type_id ║ target_id   ║ like_date           ║
╠════════╬══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 1      ║ 1        ║ 1       ║ 1049        ║ 2016-05-23 19:50:41 ║
╠════════╬══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 2      ║ 2        ║ 2       ║ 457         ║ 2016-01-09 19:50:42 ║
╠════════╬══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 3      ║ 2        ║ 3       ║ 457         ║ 2016-01-09 19:50:42 ║
╠════════╬══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 4      ║ 2        ║ 1       ║ 457         ║ 2016-01-09 19:50:42 ║
╠════════╬══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 5      ║ 3        ║ 3       ║ 4955        ║ 2016-06-12 19:50:41 ║
╚════════╩══════════╩═════════╩═════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

`type_id` columns:

- 1--> mp3s
- 2--> albums
- 3--> remixes

**i need this query like:**

```
select col1, col2, col3
from likes, mp3s, albums, remixes
     where likes.user_id == 2

          if (likes.type_id == 1)
          select col1, col2, col3
          from mp3s
          where likes.target_id == mp3s.id

          union

          if (likes.type_id == 2)
          select col1, col2, col3
          from albums
          where likes.target_id == albums.id

          union

          if (likes.type_id == 3)
          select col1, col2, col3
          from remixes
          where likes.target_id == remixes.id

 order by likes.like_date desc
 limit 0,20
```

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: @juergend convert above query to correct query :|

Comment: By the way this modelling is called polymorphic associations

Comment: @ShadyAtef what's the solution?

Comment: @grizzly I believe gbtimmon solution will work.

Comment: @ShadyAtef gbtimmon solution have not `user_id=?` and `order by like_date`.gbtimmon solution is good but not perfect solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use unions and joins

This selects all of the valid mp3 rows.

```
select 
    col1, col2, col3
from 
    likes
inner join
    mp3s
on likes.target_id = mp3s.id
where likes.type_id = 1 -- type is mp3
```

Now, so I dont do all the work for you -- create two more queries to get just the remixes and just the albums -- and then join them, maybe with a union?

Comment: `col1, col2, col3` are `mp3s, albums, remix` columns

Comment: `mp3s.mp3_name` , `mp3s.mp3_title` , `mp3s.mp3_size`

Comment: `order by like_date` is importatnt!

Comment: rename the columns in the sub querey so they come together how you want after the union with the `as` keyword. Sort the resulting set by wraping the union queries in a outer query that sorts the data set.

Comment: please edit your answer and write complete solution query with `union` and `orderby` . thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT IF(likes.type_id = 1, mp3s.col1, IF(likes.type_id = 2, albums.col1, remixes.col1)) col1,
       IF(likes.type_id = 1, mp3s.col2, IF(likes.type_id = 2, albums.col2, remixes.col2)) col2,
       IF(likes.type_id = 1, mp3s.col3, IF(likes.type_id = 2, albums.col3, remixes.col3)) col3
FROM
    likes
LEFT JOIN mp3s
    ON likes.type_id = 1 AND likes.target_id == mp3s.id
LEFT JOIN albums
    ON likes.type_id = 2 AND likes.target_id == albums.id
LEFT JOIN remixes
    ON likes.type_id = 3 AND likes.target_id == remixes.id
WHERE likes.user_id == 2
ORDER BY likes.type_id, likes.like_date desc
```